# Nutch crawler only finds a subset of links on a given page?

Tags: java, web-crawler, nutch

I'm using the following command to crawl one single page with 788 links on it:

```
nutch crawl urls/ -dir crawls -depth 1 -topN 1000
```

The above command only is able to find 72 urls! Here is the output for
`nutch readdb  ./crawls/crawldb/ -stats`:

```
CrawlDb statistics start: ./crawls/crawldb/

Statistics for CrawlDb: ./crawls/crawldb/

TOTAL urls: 72

retry 0:    72

min score:  0.009

avg score:  0.026777778

max score:  1.279

status 1 (db_unfetched):    71

status 2 (db_fetched):  1

CrawlDb statistics: done
```

My `regex-urlfilter.txt` has the default settings and I'm using Nutch 1.4.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. In my case the property `http.content.limit` was the problem. The default value is "65536". If your page is bigger, it will be truncated and links may be lost.